# Undo Pending Changes Visual Studio 2012 and TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I recently switch from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012 and it seems that "Undo Pending Changes" may be broken in the Visual Studio Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL.  I'm using TFS 2010.  When I try to undo changes I get the error "There are no changes to undo in the selection or any children of the selection" and I can't revert back to my original code.

Has anyone else observed this problem or know of a work-around?

The exact steps are:

1. Add a new file to your project. `TextFile1.txt` for example, but it can be any type of file.
2. Check in the file to TFS
3. Check out the file and add one additional line of code.
4. Save and verify that TFS is aware of the differences by doing a compare.
5. Select the file in solution explorer and right-click and select Source Control / Undo Pending Changes...

You will see the message "Warning.  There are no changes to undo in the selection or any children of the selection." OK/HELP.  Pressing OK does not revert the file to it's previous state.  (HELP doesn't help).

Comment: Doing a compare does not suggest that TFS is aware of the differences.  Doing a compare suggests that the contents on your disk differ from those on the server.  Do you actually see this item as a pending change in the Pending Changes view?

Comment: Yes, the file shows up in the Pending Changes view.

Comment: Out of curiosity, in Team Explorer's Pending Changes View, are you currently filtering on "Show Solution Changes"?

Comment: I normally have my Pending Changes view set to "Show All".  My changed file is listed if I have "Show All" or "Show Solution Changes".

Comment: This sounds like a bug that would have been fixed in any of the 5 updates that have been released after 2012 RTM. Any specific reason you haven'y installed Visual Studio 2012 update 5? I cannot repro this on my machine with update 5 installed.

Comment: Server workspace or Local workspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem. I fixed it by making a backup of my file. Then by doing a Get Latest, Undo Check out and then checked-out and put my changes back.